# C++ Efficient way to write large arrays to file with spaces in between values

Tags: c++, xml, io, ofstream

I need to write large amounts of data to an XML file. The end file will look something like this but with much more data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="RectilinearGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
  <RectilinearGrid WholeExtent="0 3 0 3 0 0">
    <Piece Extent="0 3 0 3 0 0">
      <PointData Scalars="my_scalars">
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="array" format="ascii">
          0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
        </DataArray>
      </PointData>
      <Coordinates>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="x" format="ascii">
          0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
        </DataArray>
      </Coordinates>
    </Piece>
  </RectilinearGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

To get the file started, I use `ofstream` to write the text line by line:

```
ofstream lfile;
lfile.open(filename);
lfile << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
lfile << "<VTKFile type=\"RectilinearGrid\" version=\"0.1\" byte_order=\"LittleEndian\">\n";
```

My question is about writing the sequence of numbers `0 1 2 3 ...` efficiently. This is what I do right now:

```
  lfile << "\t\t\t\t<DataArray type=\"Float32\" Name=\"array\" format=\"ascii\">\n";
  lfile << "\t\t\t\t\t";
    for (j = firsty-1; j <= lasty+1; j++){
    for (i = firstx-1; i <= lastx+1; i++){
      lfile << array[j][i][t] << " ";
    }
    }
  lfile << "\n";
  lfile << "\t\t\t\t</DataArray>\n";
```

Sometimes there could be hundreds of thousands of elements in `array`. How can I efficiently write the contents of `array` to my file in the format I have shown above?

Comment: What is wrong with what you are writing? What is "efficiently"?

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with it (in that it's working), I believe the place you're looking for is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I question the wisdom of representing megabytes' worth of binary data in XML (or any other text-based) format in the first place. You might be better off devising a binary format for that data, perhaps accompanied by a (small) XML file containing metadata, possibly all packed together in, say, a ZIP file.

Comment: I think you reference this in your question, but the last index, whatever the array size is for it, will cause the thing to skip along memory in skips that size long. This isn't so good for your cache. You want the most frequently changing index to be the last one, the least frequently changing index to be the first one. Not sure if you can change that or not. It's just an observation.

Comment: @PasserBy I'm not sure. I'm new to C++ so I normally assume that the way I have coded something is inefficient or inelegant!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, the standard data format for Paraview (a scientific computing visualization software) is VTK/XML. It is possible to write it in binary somehow, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: @UKMonkey Thank you -- I wasn't aware of that exchange.